# mysql - Invalid date error when creating stored generated column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to add a generated column for an existing table.

Within the table, there is a `varchar` column containing data like `321njkfvds_10911342`

If I add the generated column as `VIRTUAL`, **it works well!**.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD COLUMN `PartitionKey` INT 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IFNULL(TO_DAYS(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Sequence`, '_', -1)), 0)) VIRTUAL
    AFTER `Sequence`;
```

But if I try to add it as `STORED` generated column, it fails.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
  ADD COLUMN `PartitionKey` INT 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IFNULL(TO_DAYS(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Sequence`, '_', -1)), 0)) STORED 
    AFTER `Sequence`;
```

> Error Code: 1292
> Incorrect datetime value: '10911342'

I know `10911342` is not a valid date, but at least its generated column is `0` when `VIRTUAL` specified.

But why can't I add the generated column as `STORED` while `VIRTUAL` works?  is there some way to fix it?

```
@@version            
---------------------
10.3.27-MariaDB-log
```

Comment: Please add the versions you are using for mysql and mariadb

Comment: @P.Salmon added :)

Comment: I get the same error in 10.4.5 but in my view the virtual option is incorrect. No way to 'fix' that I know of - actually looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Is this a bug or expected behavior? Since stored is actually inserting a column, that has different rules over just reading a column.  I'm not sure if there would be a work around for this.  Would be interested to know if there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Generated (Virtual and Persistent/Stored) Columns :: Making Stored
> Values Consistent](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#making-stored-values-consistent)
>
> ...
>
> When a generated column is PERSISTENT or indexed, the value of the expression needs to be consistent regardless of the [SQL Mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) flags in the current session. If it is not, then the table will be seen as corrupted when the value that should actually be returned by the computed expression and the value that was previously stored and/or indexed using a different [sql_mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) setting disagree.
>
> ...

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=de312ffca4e85fabf4e336aa923f0fc1).